# :focus for select box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to give a border for select box through jquery. Although the border works for text fields, its not getting rendered for select box. However if i add this same property through firebug or so, it renders.. 
JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bfcfQ/

```
 <select name="signup_gender" id="form-field-select-1" class="signup_gender">
      <option value="0"> Select Gender</option>
      <option value="M">Male</option>
      <option value="F">Female</option>
 </select>
 <br>

<button class="test">Submit</button>
```

jQuery :

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    signup_gender       = $('select[name="signup_gender"]').val();
    alert(signup_gender);
    if(signup_gender==0){
    $(".signup_gender").css("border","1px solid #ff0000 !important");        
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do :focus in css through jquery ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not selecting the correct element. You said `$(".signup_usertype")` but you meant `$(".signup_gender")`. See working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfcfQ/1/

Comment: Re-reading your question, there is not a way to do :focus with jQuery, but you can instead use regular CSS classes: `$(...your select box...).focus(function() { $(this).addClass('focused'); }).blur(function() { $(this).removeClass('focused'); });`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want an event handler for the element.

```
$('select#yourSelectID').focus(function() {
    // javascript/jquery alteration on the element, ie:

    $(this).css('background', '#ff0'); // will change the background to red
});
```